# swiftmail symfony duplicate check for error log / email before sending

Tags: symfony, duplicates, swiftmailer

I would like to run a **duplicate content check just before firing off an email** whcih uses **swiftmailer** inside my symph2 app to **send me dev ERROR log entries**.

this functionality sits right next to my error log to database function, where it too has a duplicate check, although that one is much easier, it uses sql.

for this one, i want to maintain the last mail sent body for atleast the next 10 emails sent, so that if my error log goes out of control, it wont keep firing me duplicate emails of the same error.

should i just collect this body onto an object that holds last 10 email bodies, and attach this to the swift mailer class?  or is there an easier way, like using something that is already embedded in swift mailer for this kind of post sending use? Or maybe a session..

**Edit**, i call swift mailer from a backend helper class, so think i can pretty much do anything there so long as its atleast semi-elegant.

**EDIT**  this is a refined version of the method that calls both the persist and firing of email

```
<?php

class someWierdClass
{
    public function addLogAction(Request $request, $persist = TRUE, $addEmail = TRUE)
    {
        $responseAdd = array();  

        if ($this->getRequest()->request->all() !== null) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->request->get('data') ? $this->getRequest()->request->get('data') : 'no_data';
            $duplicate = $this->getRequest()->request->get('duplicate', null);
        } 

        if ($addEmail) {

            $responseAdd[] = 'firedIt';
            $this->fireEmailString('You have an error log here.  <br>' . $data);
        }

        if ($persist) 
        {
            $responseAdd[] = 'persistedIt';
           $this->persistLog($data, $duplicate);
        }

        if ($responseAdd) 
        {
            $body = implode(', ', $responseAdd);
            return new Response($body);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: swift doesn't have a "memory" like that. this is something you'll have to add.

Comment: so you mention memory, yes, what direction should i be looking to create this kind of memory.  i  think since its a helper class, in back end, maybe session data.  SO im thinking of just creating an new empty obj, have a 10 elem max feature, each time a new log is created, replace/pop olg log content/new log content onto the obj, load this data into a session. Next page run, when an an error is fired, look for session, read error log, if its duplicate to the any of the 10 in the session data, dont send the email.  Thats what my php brain is telling me.  so nothing in symph OR swift for this?

Comment: Did my solution solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Log emails in a table and check that there it isn't a duplicate every time you send an email.

To do this, you should create a helper function that queries the emails table for entries who's body matches the body you would like to send.  If the query returns nothing, then you know that isn't a duplicate.  You would then send the email and log it the database.  Otherwise, if it returned (a) record(s), you would send a dev ERROR log entry.

If you would like to only check against the last 10 emails, you would do this by querying for both `$body == $new_body` and `$id >= ($total_rows-10)`

You would then inject this into the container and call it using something like this

`$this->container->get('helper')->sendEmail($body, $subject, $recipients);`

Comment: hmm thats interesting.  funny you say to log them to db, because i am already doing this, and its inside this very function that im adding the email feature.  there is already a duplicate check, if it sees a dup, then it just increments the updated count, and updated timestamp only.    ill update how im doing that in the OP..

Comment: so my code you see above now, with this in mind, you gave me thje winning idea i think.  so are you saying if i just return the duplicate check from mhy db call there, ill have that flag already?  DOH.  YES... great thanks.  right??

Comment: yes but i have to make a post to show what i did.  i will add this code when i can get it scratched up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks Dan for the idea as to using the database to do the dup check. If you notice, per your suggestion, i was already doing the dup check, but it made me think.  It helped me connect the dots.

What i have done is return the answer if its a duplicate on the response when it does the updating the database, then using that response as a flag to determine if email fires or not.  (in my case, i go further to check the updated stamp is at least +1 hour old, as opposed to the 'last 10 emails content' idea)

Heres the code.. Enjoy..

```
<?php

namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller,
    Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Log,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response,
    Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request,
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

class someWierdClass
{

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $senderArray = array('no-reply@yorudomain.com' => 'Your Website Name');

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param bool $persist
     * @param bool $addEmail
     * @return Response
     */
    public function addLogAction(Request $request, $persist = TRUE, $addEmail = TRUE)
    {
        $responseAdd = array();

        if ($this->getRequest()->request->all() !== null) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->request->get('data') ? $this->getRequest()->request->get('data') : 'no_data';
            $type = $this->getRequest()->request->get('type') ? $this->getRequest()->request->get('type') : 'no_type';
            $duplicate = $this->getRequest()->request->get('duplicate', null);
        }

        if ($addEmail) {

            $responseAdd[] = 'firedIt';
            $this->fireEmailString('You have an error log here.  <br>' . $data);
        }

        if ($persist) {
            $responseAdd[] = 'persistedIt';
            $persistResponse = $this->persistLog( $type = $data, $duplicate);

            if ($persistResponse) {
                // a dup check is done here and results of this is on the response. (e.g. $content->passesCutoff)
                $content = json_decode($persistResponse->getContent());
            }
        }

        if ( $addEmail && ( isset($content->passesCutoff) && $content->passesCutoff ))
        {
            //fire off an email also, because its kind of hard to look in teh logs all the time, sometimes we just want an email.
            $successEmail = $this->fireEmailString($data);

            if( ! $successEmail )
            {
                $responseAdd[] = 'firedIt';
            }
        }

        if ($responseAdd) {
            $body = implode(', ', $responseAdd);
            return new Response($body);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $emailStringData
     * @param null $emailSubject
     * @param null $emailTo
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function fireEmailString($emailStringData, $emailSubject = null, $emailTo=null){

        $templateName =  'AcmeBundle:Default:fireEmailString.html.twig';

        if(  ! $emailSubject )
        {
            $emailSubject = 'An email is being fired to you!' ;
        }

        if(  ! $emailTo )
        {
            $emailTo = 'youremail@gmail.com';
        }


        $renderedView  = $this->renderView(
            $templateName, array(
            'body' => $emailStringData,
        ));

        $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
        $message = $mailer->createMessage()
            ->setSubject( $emailSubject)
            ->setBody($emailStringData, 'text/plain')
            ->addPart($renderedView, 'text/html')
            ->setFrom($this->senderArray)
            ->setSender($this->senderArray)
            ->setTo($emailTo);

        $results = $mailer->send($message);
        return  $results;
    }

    /**
     * @param $type
     * @param $data
     * @param $duplicate
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    protected function persistLog($type, $data, $duplicate) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $count = null;
        $passesCutoff = null;
        $mysqlNow = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d G:i:s'));

        //only two conditions can satisy here, strings '1' and 'true'.
        if($duplicate !== '1' && $duplicate !== 'true' /*&& $duplicate != TRUE*/)
        {
            //in order to check if its unique we need to get the repo
            //returns an object (findByData() would return an array)
            $existingLog = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Log')->findOneByData(
                array('type' => $type, 'data' => $data)
            );

            if($existingLog)
            {
                $timeUpdatedString = strtotime($existingLog->getTimeupdated()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                $cutoffStamp =  strtotime('+1 hour', $timeUpdatedString); //advance 1 hour (customize this to the amount of time you want to go by before you consider this a duplicate.  i think 1 hour is good)
                $passesCutoff = time() >= $cutoffStamp ? TRUE : FALSE; //1 hour later
                $count = $existingLog->getUpdatedcount();
                $existingLog->setUpdatedcount($count + 1); // '2014-10-11 03:52:20' // date('Y-m-d G:i:s')
                $em->persist($existingLog);
            }
            else
            {  
                //this record isnt found, must be unique
                $newLog = new Log(); //load our entity

                //set in new values
                $newLog->setType($type);
                $newLog->setData($data);
                $newLog->setUpdatedcount(0);
                $newLog->setTimeupdated($mysqlNow);

                $em->persist($newLog);
            }
        }
        else
        {  
            //we dont care if unique or not, we just want a new row
            $newLog = new Log(); //load our entity
            $newLog->setType($type);
            $newLog->setData($data);

            //time updated has been set to auto update to current timestamp in the schema, test first, then remove this
            $newLog->setUpdatedcount(0);
            $newLog->setTimeupdated($mysqlNow);

            $em->persist($newLog);
        }

        $em->flush();
        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setData(
            array(
                'data' => 'persistedIt',
                'existingLog' => $count,
                'passesCutoff' => $passesCutoff,
            ));

        return $response;
    }

}
```

In hindsight, i would have just passed the last update timestamp back on the response from the persist method, then do the cutoff calculation inside the fire email method obviously, but the above code does work as a starting point.. :-)